# Pronunciation of е in different words

Tags: произношение

So from what I have learnt so far, нет is pronounced "nyet" and Привет is "privyet". But in телефон it is "telefon", why is е used in this case and not э and why is it not pronounced "tyelyefon"?

I'm really new to learning Russian so simpler answers will be much appreciated :)

Comment: None of given pronunciations is correct. And what would be the difference between "telefon" and "tyelyefon" in your opinion?

Comment: How would I pronounce them then? And would there not be more of an emphasis on the y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the "pronunciations" you quote are just rough renderings of Russian pronunciation using English spelling and are all about equally wrong. Perhaps you should look at the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) of those words:

- [нет](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82#Pronunciation_2) [nʲet]
- [привет](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82#Pronunciation) [prʲɪˈvʲet]
- [телефон](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD#Pronunciation_6) [tʲɪlʲɪˈfon]

The superscript j indicates the [softness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)) of the preceding consonant and is *not* a separate sound. E.g. these are two distinct words:

- сел [sʲel] (sat)
- съел [sjel] (ate)

As to why some e's are pronounced [e] and some [ɪ], those are effects of vowel reduction in unstressed syllables.

Comment: What is the superscript j in those words? I've never seen this form before? this is all new to me!

Comment: @redward01 - What's the textbook you're using to learn Russian?

Comment: In case you haven't googled it yet (which I strongly suggest you do before asking any question), here's the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)

Comment: @YellowSky I am currently just using duolingo, im not sure how good it is but its useful. Do you have any books to recommend?